# Object collision OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, collision-detection, glut

Hello I need help trying to figure out how to check if my car has hit an object or not. I am trying to implement the AABB since they are simple cubes however it doesn't seem to be working. I was wondering if anyone could help me solve this?

Below you can see my locations and sizes for my car. Then there's the function that draws the car, the object and the one that checks the collision.

```
float xPos = 80, yPos = 0, zPos = 0, xRot = 0, yRot = 0, angle = 0.0;

float carFront[] = {xPos - 8, 1, zPos + 8};
float carFrontSizeX = 2;
float carFrontSizeY = 1;
float carFrontSizeZ = 1;

float carBack[] = {xPos - 8, 1, zPos + 10};

float obj[] = {xPos, yPos, zPos};
float objSizeX = 1;
float objSizeY = 1;
float objSizeZ = 1;

bool pauseGame = false;
bool collision = false;




void drawTruck(){

    //front of truck
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(carFront[0], carFront[1], carFront[2]);
        glScalef(carFrontSizeX, carFrontSizeY, carFrontSizeZ);
        glColor3f(0,0,0);
        glutWireCube(2);
        glColor3f(1,0,1);
        glutSolidCube(2);
    glPopMatrix();
    //back of truck
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(carBack[0], carBack[1], carBack[2]);
        glColor3f(0,0,0);
        glutWireCube(4);
        glColor3f(1,0,1);
        glutSolidCube(4);
    glPopMatrix();

    

} 

void drawRandomObjects(){
    
    glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(objSizeX, objSizeY, objSizeZ); //size of object
        //left object
        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(obj[0] - 4, obj[1] + 1, obj[3] - 100);
            glColor3f(0,0,0); glutWireCube(2);
            glColor3f(0,1,0); glutSolidCube(2);
        glPopMatrix();
        //right object
        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(obj[0] + 4, obj[1] + 1, obj[3] - 130);
            glColor3f(0,0,0); glutWireCube(2);
            glColor3f(0,1,0); glutSolidCube(2);
        glPopMatrix();
    
    glPopMatrix();

    glutPostRedisplay();

}

bool checkCollision(){

    //it's checking to see if objects are touching
    if(obj[0] - objSizeX <= carFront[0] + carFrontSizeX &&
       obj[0] + objSizeX >= carFront[0] - carFrontSizeX &&
       obj[1] - objSizeY <= carFront[1] + carFrontSizeY &&
       obj[1] + objSizeY >= carFront[1] - carFrontSizeY &&
       obj[2] - objSizeZ <= carFront[2] + carFrontSizeZ &&
       obj[2] + objSizeZ >= carFront[2] - carFrontSizeZ) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }

}

//Timer function is called in every MSEC_PER_FRAME milliseconds
void timerFunc(int value){

    //truck moves forward
    if(!pauseGame){
        carFront[2]--;
        carBack[2]--;
        collision = checkCollision();
    }
    //check for collision. If objects touch pause game
    if(collision){
        pauseGame = true;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc (MSEC_PER_FRAME, timerFunc, value);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `//it's checking to see if objects are touching` test be or (`||`) tests ? As the collision can be along any of the axis of bounding box(s).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mre]. Please also take a tour on how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/

Comment: fyi, `glPushMatrix`, `glTranslate`, `glColor` etc are all deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that come to my mind when I see this first

```
if(obj[0] - objSizeX <= carFront[0] + carFrontSizeX &&
       obj[0] + objSizeX >= carFront[0] - carFrontSizeX &&
       obj[1] - objSizeY <= carFront[1] + carFrontSizeY &&
       obj[1] + objSizeY >= carFront[1] - carFrontSizeY &&
       obj[2] - objSizeZ <= carFront[2] + carFrontSizeZ &&
       obj[2] + objSizeZ >= carFront[2] - carFrontSizeZ) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
```

have you tried using or ( `||` ) instead of and?

Second I don't see why are you calling the object on the comparison maybe you should create a single car on an individual object and do:

```
if((car1.getX - sizeX) - (car2.getX - sizeX)) <= 0 )
{
    /* collide */
}
```

If the 2 get subtracted and the result is 0 or less means it's colliding (I might be wrong with what I say)

And also don't just do the comparison with AABB you need an octree, to reduce the number of comparisons or the game will become slow.

```
if (bpy - rads < 0 && vvy < 0) {
    vvy *= bonc;

    if(vvy < 9)
    {
         vvy = 0; force_y = 0;
    }

    bpy = 0 + rads;                        
}

if ((bpx+rads > 500 && vvx > 0)||(bpx-rads < -500 && vvx < 0)) {
    dir_x*=-1;
    vvx*=-1;
}
```

idk if this might help you it's the collision of a sphere with the world border vvx is the velocity on X and vvy velocity on Y

Comment: also if you want some collision more simple you can use an array and a raycaster and just move the elements inside the array